# Unit testing for event in meteor application: set event and template parameter

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js, chai

I need to do a test for an event, which is using a ReactiveDict:

**imports/ui/example.js**

```
'click li': function(event, template) {
    const   $this = $(event.currentTarget),
            type  = $this.attr('data-type');

    template.dict.set('section', type);
},
```

I've added `xolvio:template-isolator` to use `fireEvent()`:

**imports/ui/example.test.js**

```
import { expect } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import { fireEvent } from 'meteor/xolvio:template-isolator';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './example.js';

describe('Events', function() {
    it('set selected type', function (done) {
        const expectedValue = 'anything';
        Template.example.fireEvent('click li'); 
        expect(reactiveVar).to.be.equal(expectedValue);
        done();
    });
});
```

But I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined`.
And how do I get the ReactiveDict-Value?

In the docs of `xolvio:template-isolator` there is this example to add parameters - which I think I have to do:

```
fireEvent('myEvent', {
    context: { some: 'values' },
    event: { { which: 13, target: {value: ''}} },
    templateInstance: new Template('myNewTemplate', function() {})
});
```

But I don't know how to adapt that to my needs to set `events` and `template` of the function.

Comment: Have you tried the technique described [here](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#simple-blaze-unit-test) in Meteor Guide? The `Blaze.renderWithData` method returns a `View` object that can be used to access the template instance, so in particular your reactive dict object.